# How to update the parent field in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

My data looks like this

```
ID Text IsParent ParentID
-------------------------
1  A    1        NULL
2  B    0        NULL
3  C    0        NULL
4  D    0        NULL
5  E    1        NULL
6  F    0        NULL
7  G    1        NULL
8  H    0        NULL
```

I want to fill `ParentID` with the previous `parentID`.

Data is ordered so

```
ID : 2,3,4 have parentID : 1
ID : 6 has parentID : 5
ID : 8 has parentID : 7
```

How to do this with SQL?

I have tried with a cursor, but it is way too slow.

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR
    SELECT ID Text IsParent ParentID 
    FROM x2 
    ORDER BY ID

OPEN cur1

FETCH NEXT FROM cur1 INTO @ID, @Text, @IsParent, @ParentID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF @IsParent = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @LastParentID = @ID
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE X2 
        SET ParentID = @LastParentID 
        WHERE ID = @ID
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur1 INTO @ID, @Text, @IsParent, @ParentID
END;

CLOSE cur1;
DEALLOCATE cur1;
```

Comment: @DaleK I added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [`APPLY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-apply). The premise is to find the parent record with the highest ID, where the ID is lower than the child record.

**Example**

```
DECLARE @x2 TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL, Text CHAR(1), IsParent BIT, ParentID INT);
INSERT @x2 (ID, Text, IsParent)
VALUES
    (1, 'A', 1), (2, 'B', 0), (3, 'C', 0), (4, 'D', 0),
    (5, 'E', 1), (6, 'F', 0), (7, 'G', 1), (8, 'H', 0);

UPDATE  c
SET     ParentID = p.ID
FROM    @x2 AS c
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 ID 
            FROM    @x2 AS p
            WHERE   p.IsParent = 1  -- Is a parent record
            AND     p.ID < c.ID     -- ID is lower than child record
            ORDER BY p.ID DESC      -- Order descending to get the highest ID
        ) AS p
WHERE   c.IsParent = 0
AND     c.ParentID IS NULL;

SELECT  *
FROM    @x2;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ID  Text    IsParent    ParentID
---------------------------------
1   A       1           NULL
2   B       0           1
3   C       0           1
4   D       0           1
5   E       1           NULL
6   F       0           5
7   G       1           NULL
8   H       0           7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CTE and window function to achieve that.

First we are creating continuous id(`cid`) using `sum` and secondly picking the minimum `ID` using the `cid` created in the first step and then finally updating the table where `IsParent` is 0.

try the following:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT *, sum(t.IsParent) OVER (ORDER BY id) cid
    FROM @t t
),
cte2 AS
(
    SELECT *, min(id) OVER (PARTITION BY cid ORDER BY id) pid
    FROM cte c
)
UPDATE t
SET
    t.ParentID = pid
FROM @t t
JOIN cte2 c  ON c.id = t.ID
WHERE c.IsParent = 0
```

db<>fiddle **[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0d3b14f34f2199bcc6d4802cd2243de1)**.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way would be to insert child records with the parent id.  Instead of populating the parent ids after the fact.  From code you would first insert parent records and get back the newly generated parent ids.  Then insert the child records with those newly generated parent ids.

Trying to maintain a query's speed like the ones suggested would just get gross over time as the data grows. Just because you can, doesn't mean you should.

Also as a side note, if you plan on having child of child records with an unknown depth.  To avoid recursion I would recommend looking into having a hierarchyid data type column.